# ui-router Angularjs controller not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**LAST EDIT : for those who use angular material, NEVER** put a view like this

`<md-content layout-padding="">
    <div ui-view="addOppo"></div>
 </md-content>`

You have to directly do

`<md-content ui-view="addOppo" layout-padding=""> </md-content>`

**Why ? Because this will destroy your controller function**

---

Here is my problem, AddClientController is not loaded so the view is loaded but not my controller. The name is good, i use it in another part of the application and it work. But when i want to re-use the addClient controller somewhere else with his view, only the view is loaded. I really don't anderstand why ui-router does not load it. Thanks in advance.

```
  function getStates() {
return [
{
  state: 'dashboard.addOpportunite',
  config: {
    url: '/addOpportunite',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/commerciaux/addOpportunite/addOpportunite.html',
        controller: 'AddOpportuniteController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
      },
      'addOppo@dashboard.addOpportunite': {
        templateUrl: 'app/clients/add/addClient.html',
        controller: 'AddClientController',
        controllerAs: 'vm2',
      }
    },
    title: 'Ajout Opportunite',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
      label: 'Ajout Opportunite'
    }
  }
}
];
```

}

"Why do you say that the controller is not loaded ? How do you know this ?"
I have a form in the addClient.html and some console.log that does not appear.

edit, i had a part of the addOpportunite.html :

```
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right" md-component-id="right" md-whiteframe="4">
    <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
      <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-padding="">
    <div ui-view="addOppo"></div>
      <md-button ng-click="vm.closeRightMenu()" class="md-primary">
        Close Sidenav Right
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </md-sidenav>
```

**I finally found that my controller was called but the main problem now is that the 2 controller use same named fonction so the children view controller doesn't call his function but the parent one.(eg : i have `function activate(){} //in all my controllers` So last question, what is the best way to implement function to clearly differenciate with parent controller function? Rename ? controller As ? I actually based my dev on john papa's hotowel but i don't really see in his style guide a tips for my question. Where i can found another good style guide for this case ?**

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the correct view ? Why do you say that the controller is not loaded ? How do you know this ?

Comment: Could you share the content of the app/commerciaux/addOpportunite/addOpportunite.html .. and also, maybe share more of your code.. index.html

Comment: "Are you sure that you are on the correct view ?" The view is loaded, i see my addClient.html in my "ui-view=addOppo"